# What's blocking this IFrame from being loaded?

Tags: html, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to add an IFrame to a page.

The page:
https://www.homedepot.com/order/view/tracking

The code I'm using to add this IFrame:

```
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();

  // Change this to div.childNodes to support multiple top-level nodes
  return div.firstChild; 
}
element = createElementFromHTML(`<div id='testing-iframe'>
  <iframe src='chrome-extension://zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz/index.html'></iframe>
<div>`)
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Now, notice the URL starts with `chrome-extension://`. Different protocol.

On the above homedepot.com page, when I inspect `#testing-iframe`, I see no IFrame. It's like the browser rejects the element.

On most other websites on the internet, such as https://example.com/, the IFrame element shows on inspection (no content though, as this is a dummy URL).

Please see screenshot:
[image]

See, on example.com I do get an IFrame. On homedepot.com I don't.

Another thing to point out, as said earlier this happens when I'm using a different protocol, `chrome-extension`. But, when I'm using an HTTPS URL such as https://www.texasauto.com/ it DOES WORK, on both pages.

So far regarding the problem.

**My question is: What's causing it?**

I assume this is some HTTP header.
First I was suspecting the `Strict-Transport-Security` header.
So, I tried to disable it with another extension, but it didn't fix it.
Then I tried to disable more headers, and also add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, yet it didn't work.

**Any idea what's causing the problem?**

**Edit**: Headers returned by homedepot.com:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8081
access-control-max-age: 0
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
content-encoding: gzip
content-language: he
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 29 May 2021 22:16:06 GMT
expires: Sat, 29 May 2021 22:16:06 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
server-timing: edge; dur=153
server-timing: origin; dur=75
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Sat, 29-May-2021 23:16:06 GMT; path=/; domain=homedepot.com; secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; preload
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-akamai-transformed: 9 153137 0 pmb=mTOE,1mRUM,2
x-application-context: orders-purchases-ui:prod:8080
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-device-type: desktop
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-proto: secure
x-tm-zone: us-east4-a
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What response headers (and values) _does_ that page return?

Comment: @Ivar No errors. And, response headers are in the question (edited).

Comment: My best guess would be that it is caused by the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header. Though I'd expect that `https://www.texasauto.com/` would also be prevented from working.

Comment: The extension must expose this html file in its `web_accessible_resources`. If it does, then you either have another extension that interferes or it's a bug in the browser (`x-frame-options` is mistakenly applied to the extension's frame), which you can report on https://crbug.com (see if it's reported already first).

Comment: From the docs: "The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a <frame>, <iframe>, <embed> or <object>. Sites can use this to avoid click-jacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.". I appreciate the try but that's not the case. @wOxxOm got the idea but I believe `X-Frame-Options` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Not sure you got the idea which was that the browser intentionally ignores these restrictions for chrome-extension:// iframes and that it's possible there's a bug in the browser as it still applies the restriction here.

Comment: @wOxxOm I got it, but didn't move forward with this. Thanks for the suggestion though :)